# Add custom getter to received json

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js, vuejs2, single-page-application

what is the best way to add custom getter to json, which is often used in some view? For instance consider json which represent user object. This json has fields like `firstName`, `lastName`, 'age', and so on. When I want render label with user name in Vue components, I want label like this: `firstName + ' ' + lastName + '(' + age + ')'`

I would like have new field or getter in this json, in whole my SPA application. I have this ideas:

- receive json from axios, and modify this json like this: `responseData.fullName = responseData.firstName + ' ' + responseData.lastName + '(' + responseData.age + ')'`
- map json to class object which will mapp all fields and will have getter to concat full name, like this: user = new User(responseData)
- or some other way which I didn't mention?

I am new in developing single page apps so I will be grateful for any advice.

Answer (score 1):

you can add getter to your User class

```
class User {     
  get fullName() {
    return `${this.firstName} ${this.lastName} (${this.age})`
  }
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get

Consider to use computed properties:

```
export default {
  name: 'SomeComponent',
  computed: {
    userFullName() {
      return this.user ? `${this.user.firstName} ${this.user.lastName} (${this.user.age})` : '';
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      user: null
    };
  },
  methods: {
    async loadData() {
      this.user = await axios.get('');
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: hi, thank you for effort. I know how to do that, I just asking if it good practice map json to class object where will be getter placed or there is another used way :)

Comment: @DenisStephanov 
I'm sorry. I think i didn't understand clearly what you asked. I don't see anything bad in mapping json to object which has a getter. But i would rather use a component computed property for this purpose.

Comment: @DenisStephanov I've added to my answer example of use computed property

Comment: But I need use full name in multiple components, with this way I need create computed property on multiple components and duplicate code.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a function like this. It gets a parameter of an object with properties of 'firstName' and 'lastName' and destructures it.
Here is link about Destructuring.

https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Then use template literals.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

```
function getFullName({ firstName, lastName}) { 
    return `${firstName} ${lastName}`;
}

console.log(getFullName(responseData));

// prints for example: Denis Stephanov
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.